# authentication fail in laravel and sentry package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

im trying to use Sentry 2 in my new application to handle all users and groups .
after authenticate user with sentry and when trying to redirect to another page the authentication lost 
in the test code the output of the check function `Sentry::check()` is true

```
public function Login(){
               $credentials = array(
                        'username'    => 'Mouad',
                        'password' => 'test',
                    );

                // Authenticate the user
               $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
               var_dump(Sentry::check());


    }
```

session output

```
array (size=3)
  '_token' => string 'slAqB8IYYrSPPSC1k1A2i8aTpkpVklPad3fiqoFA' (length=40)
  'flash' => 
    array (size=2)
      'old' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'new' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  'cartalyst_sentry' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => null
      1 => string '$2y$08$nWq4rHlacrNykXhQykipJ.0c8mr6VK4o364UvatPtJZ1kM1W8KH7K' (length=60)
```

when i tried to redirect the page after authentication the 'cartalyst_sentry' session entry changed and output of the check function `Sentry::check()` is false

```
 public function Login(){
               $credentials = array(
                        'username'    => 'Mouad',
                        'password' => 'test',
                    );

                // Authenticate the user
               $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
               return Redirect::to('admin');


    }
    public function Admin(){
        $data = Session::all();
        var_dump($data);
        var_dump(Sentry::check());
    }
```

the route configuration is simple

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@Index');
Route::get('create', 'MainController@Create');
Route::get('login', 'MainController@Login');
Route::get('admin', 'MainController@Admin');
Route::get('logout', 'MainController@Logout');
```

session configuration is default and Storage folder is writable

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

**Login Controller**:

```
public function store() {
        if (Input::get('remember') == "") {
            $remember = false;
        } else {
            $remember = true;
        }
        $user = [
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        ];

        $login = User::login($user, $remember);

    }
```

**User Model** (`$login` is call to modal user):

```
public static function login(array $credentials, $remember) {
    try {
        $user = Sentry::findUserByCredentials($credentials);

       // PROCESS TO THE LOGIN AND REDIRECT TO THE DASHBOARD PAGE
          $user->is_logged_in = 1;
          $user->save();
          Sentry::login($user, $remember);    
          return \Redirect::route('admin.dashboard.index');

    } catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['auth_message' => 'U moet alle velden in vullen']);
    } catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['auth_message' => 'U moet het wachtwoordveld invullen']);
    } catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\WrongPasswordException $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['auth_message' => 'Het opgegeven email/wachtwoord is onjuist']);
    } catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['auth_message' => 'Het opgegeven email/wachtwoord is onjuist']);
    } catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotActivatedException $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['auth_message' => 'Dit account is nog niet geactiveerd']);
    } catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Throttling\UserSuspendedException $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['auth_message' => 'Dit account heeft een timeout']);
    } catch (\Cartakyst\Sentry\Throttling\UserBannedExveption $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors(['auth_message' => 'Dit account is van onze site verbannen']);
    }
}
```